# can DateDiff tell the hourly difference between different days?

Tags: coldfusion

I am using datediff("h",TimeFormat(stamp), TimeFormat(now)) and checking for a difference gt than 7.  If the time is greater than 7 it will update the stamp.  It only checks every now and then so its possible for a day to go by with no check.  Will the datediff understand that 5AM tuesday is 24 hrs different than 5AM wednesday?

Comment: It's actually the `TimeFormat` that was giving you the problem. Both values in the case you cited would have been changed to `05:00 AM` and the result would have been `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if the variable 'stamp' is a full date/time, then yes.  it will correctly calculate the # of hours between value 1 and value 2.

You don't need to format the values passed in either.  dateFormat() and timeFormat() are display functions meant to make a date/time value presentable to a human reader.  A function (such as dateDiff(), dateAdd(), etc) doesn't need the date value to be formatted in any specific way.  It just needs it to be a valid date/time value.

So assuming:

stamp = createDateTime( 2010, 11, 21, 1, 0, 0 ); // creates a date/time of nov 21, 2010 1:00am

dateDiff( 'h', stamp, now ); // this will work.  no need for formatting functions.